# Simple way to encrypt strings with Polish characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, encryption

What I want to achieve is for Polish characters to encrypt and decrypt. What I do know is that usually "UTF-8"or "windows-1250" works, but the question would be more where to put it.

Here is the working example from a close question, but without the specific characters:

```
def encode(key, string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        encoded_c = chr(ord(string[i]) + ord(key_c) % 256)
        encoded_chars.append(encoded_c)
    encoded_string = ''.join(encoded_chars)
    return encoded_string

def decode(key, string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        encoded_c = chr((ord(string[i]) - ord(key_c) + 256) % 256)
        encoded_chars.append(encoded_c)
    encoded_string = ''.join(encoded_chars)
    return encoded_string

e = encode('MarcelProjectNoName', 'ąężłóćńś')
d = decode('MarcelProjectNoName', e)
print(e)
print(d)
```

This code returns:

```
ŒźǮƥŘųƔǍ
|BóD[
```

Comment: Sad fact: There's no easy way to implement a Caesar cipher for arbitrary Unicode text. Unicode is not as simple as "every codepoint in this sequence is one character" which is a requirement for this kind of cipher. What you can do is define a subset of characters for which this holds that includes all the special characters that you want to support.

Comment: (The original code "works" for simple 8 bit encodings such as Windows 1252, so if polish  works with it, that's an alternative solution. Although you'd still get invisible control characters which you can't display - not that useful either)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a simple method, encode your strings to bytes and use XOR when iterating through the string and key.  The advantage is the same function can be used for encrypt/decrypt.  Note that `.encode()` default is `utf8`:

```
def encrypt(key, string):
    return bytes([b ^ key[i % len(key)] for i,b in enumerate(string)])

decrypt = encrypt

key = 'MarcelProjectNoName'.encode()
e = encrypt(key, 'ąężłóćńś'.encode())
d = decrypt(key, e)

print(e)
print(d.decode())
```

Output:

```
b'\x89\xe4\xb6\xfa\xa0\xd0\x95\xf0\xac\xd9\xa1\xe4\xb1\xca\xaa\xd5'
ąężłóćńś
```

Comment: Hello, it does work but the "encrypted" string is not very extremely hard to break into. Would there be any better ways of doing this where the string would be safer?

Comment: @Marcel You wanted simple. Your Caesar cipher is simple as well. simple != hard to break. Google “Python cryptography” for better examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built-in `str.encode` and `bytes.decode` methods instead:

```
s = 'MarcelProjectNoName'
e = s.encode('utf-8')
d = e.decode('utf-8')
```